Maven Build Cache Extension Cache Hit Metric
I am experimenting with Maven Build Cache Extension 1.2.0 and Maven 3.9.9 in a multi-module Maven project.
Is there a way to get some metrics around the cache hit rate per Maven module?

This is answered in maven mailing list. Summarizing the discussion

There is something very minimal in target/maven-incremental/cache-report*. Format available here. As of version 1.2.0 version of the maven-build-cache-extension plugin there is no support to aggregate/report those values.


There is no configurable option to change the cache report path. If this is necessary, the execution of copy-resources can be leveraged.

